# Select multiple ListItems in an <asp:ListBox> from codebehind c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I've got a `ListBox(with selectionMode=multiple)` and store the selected values in a cookie. 
When the user comes back I want to provide him with all the options selected again.

What I do so far: I get all the selected values and store the indices ","-separated in a string in the cookie.

When the user comes back I split the string and loop through all ListItems to select each one again!

but with:

```
foreach (string str in selectedStr)
{
    listbox1.SelectedIndex = Int32.Parse(str);
}
```

I only get one (random?) selected value.

Can anyone help me to get all the selected values selected again?
maybe even a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through your splitted string array, and access the `ListBox.Items[]` based on the index and set the `Selected` property to true.

```
foreach (string str in selectedStr)
{
    listbox1.Items[Int32.Parse(str)].Selected = true;
}
```

*Make sure that `str` is indeed an integer and its in range with `Items.Length`*

Comment: I get an error that I cannot index System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox with "[]"

Comment: @Sammy46, its `listBox1.Items[]`, not `ListBox[]`, please check the code in answer

Comment: @Habib thank you for your fast help! But it seems I'm still doing something wrong. I've got 31 Items in my ListBox but no matter which index I try to access with listbox1.Items[x].Selected = true; I get an out of range exception... any ideas whats is going wrong here?

Comment: @Sammy46, are you storing indices or values in the string ?

Comment: @Habib Problem solved!:) I generate the ListBox dynamically and I tried to access the Items before the call of Data.Bind(). Thanks a lot for your super fast help!

Answer (score 3):

Just try using `FindByValue` property of Listview as follow...

```
foreach (string str in selectedStr)
{
    if(listbox1.Items.FindByValue(str) != null) 
    { 
          listbox1.Items.FindByValue(str).Selected = true; 
    } 
}
```